# cannot login to admin after seemly successful installation

Tags: magento2, admin, error, login

when I try to login to admin panel, the following error occurred

```
There has been an error processing your request
Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.
Error log record number: 363200370184
```

So I investigated `363200370184`

```
{"0":"Image CAPTCHA requires GD extension","1":"<pre>#1 Magento\\Captcha\\Model\\DefaultModel->__construct(&Magento\\Backend\\Model\\Auth\\Session\\Interceptor#000000007de0b08f0000000016f2016c#, &Magento\\Captcha\\Helper\\Adminhtml\\Data#000000007de0b2190000000016f2016c#, &Magento\\Captcha\\Model\\ResourceModel\\LogFactory#000000007de0b21f0000000016f2016c#, 'backend_login', NULL) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/Factory\/AbstractFactory.php:111]\n#2 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Factory\\AbstractFactory->createObject('Magento\\Captcha\\...', array(&Magento\\Backend\\Model\\Auth\\Session\\Interceptor#000000007de0b08f0000000016f2016c#, &Magento\\Captcha\\Helper\\Adminhtml\\Data#000000007de0b2190000000016f2016c#, &Magento\\Captcha\\Model\\ResourceModel\\LogFactory#000000007de0b21f0000000016f2016c#, 'backend_login', NULL)) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/Factory\/Dynamic\/Developer.php:66]\n#3 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Factory\\Dynamic\\Developer->create('Magento\\Captcha\\...', array('formId' => 'backend_login')) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/ObjectManager.php:56]\n#4 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\ObjectManager->create('Magento\\Captcha\\...', array('formId' => 'backend_login')) called at [vendor\/magento\/module-captcha\/Model\/CaptchaFactory.php:37]\n#5 Magento\\Captcha\\Model\\CaptchaFactory->create('DefaultModel', 'backend_login') called at [vendor\/magento\/module-captcha\/Helper\/Data.php:100]\n#6 Magento\\Captcha\\Helper\\Data->getCaptcha('backend_login') called at [vendor\/magento\/module-captcha\/Observer\/CheckUserLoginBackendObserver.php:53]\n#7 Magento\\Captcha\\Observer\\CheckUserLoginBackendObserver->execute(&Magento\\Framework\\Event\\Observer#000000007de0b2620000000016f2016c#) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Event\/Invoker\/InvokerDefault.php:88]\n#8 Magento\\Framework\\Event\\Invoker\\InvokerDefault->_callObserverMethod(&Magento\\Captcha\\Observer\\CheckUserLoginBackendObserver#000000007de0b2450000000016f2016c#, &Magento\\Framework\\Event\\Observer#000000007de0b2620000000016f2016c#) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Event\/Invoker\/InvokerDefault.php:74]\n#9 Magento\\Framework\\Event\\Invoker\\InvokerDefault->dispatch(array('instance' => 'Magento\\Captcha\\...', 'name' => 'captcha'), &Magento\\Framework\\Event\\Observer#000000007de0b2620000000016f2016c#) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Event\/Manager.php:66]\n#10 Magento\\Framework\\Event\\Manager->dispatch('admin_user_authe...', array('username' => 'shinta', 'user' => &Magento\\User\\Model\\User\\Interceptor#000000007de0b2770000000016f2016c#)) called at [generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/Event\/Manager\/Proxy.php:95]\n#11 Magento\\Framework\\Event\\Manager\\Proxy->dispatch('admin_user_authe...', array('username' => 'shinta', 'user' => &Magento\\User\\Model\\User\\Interceptor#000000007de0b2770000000016f2016c#)) called at [vendor\/magento\/module-user\/Model\/User.php:631]\n#12 Magento\\User\\Model\\User->authenticate('shinta', 'xxxxxxxxxx') called at [generated\/code\/Magento\/User\/Model\/User\/Interceptor.php:193]\n#13 Magento\\User\\Model\\User\\Interceptor->authenticate('shinta', 'xxxxxxxxxx') called at [vendor\/magento\/module-user\/Model\/User.php:687]\n#14 Magento\\User\\Model\\User->login('shinta', 'xxxxxxxxxx') called at [generated\/code\/Magento\/User\/Model\/User\/Interceptor.php:219]\n#15 Magento\\User\\Model\\User\\Interceptor->login('shinta', 'xxxxxxxxxx') called at [vendor\/magento\/module-backend\/Model\/Auth.php:156]\n#16 Magento\\Backend\\Model\\Auth->login('shinta', 'xxxxxxxxxx') called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:58]\n#17 Magento\\Backend\\Model\\Auth\\Interceptor->___callParent('login', array('shinta', 'xxxxxxxxxx')) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:138]\n#18 Magento\\Backend\\Model\\Auth\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}('shinta', 'xxxxxxxxxx') called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:153]\n#19 Magento\\Backend\\Model\\Auth\\Interceptor->___callPlugins('login', array('shinta', 'xxxxxxxxxx'), array(array('security_admin_s...'))) called at [generated\/code\/Magento\/Backend\/Model\/Auth\/Interceptor.php:78]\n#20 Magento\\Backend\\Model\\Auth\\Interceptor->login('shinta', 'xxxxxxxxxx') called at [vendor\/magento\/module-backend\/App\/Action\/Plugin\/Authentication.php:205]\n#21 Magento\\Backend\\App\\Action\\Plugin\\Authentication->_performLogin(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#000000007de0b1eb0000000016f2016c#) called at [vendor\/magento\/module-backend\/App\/Action\/Plugin\/Authentication.php:157]\n#22 Magento\\Backend\\App\\Action\\Plugin\\Authentication->_processNotLoggedInUser(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#000000007de0b1eb0000000016f2016c#) called at [vendor\/magento\/module-backend\/App\/Action\/Plugin\/Authentication.php:125]\n#23 Magento\\Backend\\App\\Action\\Plugin\\Authentication->aroundDispatch(&Magento\\Backend\\Controller\\Adminhtml\\Index\\Index\\Interceptor#000000007de0b3380000000016f2016c#, &Closure#000000007de0b3300000000016f2016c#, &Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#000000007de0b1eb0000000016f2016c#) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:135]\n#24 Magento\\Backend\\Controller\\Adminhtml\\Index\\Index\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#000000007de0b1eb0000000016f2016c#) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:153]\n#25 Magento\\Backend\\Controller\\Adminhtml\\Index\\Index\\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', array(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#000000007de0b1eb0000000016f2016c#), NULL) called at [generated\/code\/Magento\/Backend\/Controller\/Adminhtml\/Index\/Index\/Interceptor.php:39]\n#26 Magento\\Backend\\Controller\\Adminhtml\\Index\\Index\\Interceptor->dispatch(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#000000007de0b1eb0000000016f2016c#) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/FrontController.php:55]\n#27 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController->dispatch(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#000000007de0b1eb0000000016f2016c#) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:58]\n#28 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', array(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#000000007de0b1eb0000000016f2016c#)) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:138]\n#29 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#000000007de0b1eb0000000016f2016c#) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:153]\n#30 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', array(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#000000007de0b1eb0000000016f2016c#), array(array('default_store_se...', 'storeCookieValid...', 'install', 'configHash'))) called at [generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/App\/FrontController\/Interceptor.php:26]\n#31 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->dispatch(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#000000007de0b1eb0000000016f2016c#) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Http.php:136]\n#32 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http->launch() called at [generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/App\/Http\/Interceptor.php:24]\n#33 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor->launch() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Bootstrap.php:257]\n#34 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Bootstrap->run(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor#000000007de0b1990000000016f2016c#) called at [index.php:39]\n<\/pre>","url":"\/admin\/admin\/index\/index\/key\/b4625ae2ff3073ab297b349a5a752c7ca652f946f569480aaad9f498a564afcf\/","script_name":"\/index.php"}
```

What could possibly be wrong?

My env

> ubuntu 18.04
>
> magento 2.2.9
>
> php 7.1

I installed php by the official command:

```
apt-get install -y php7.1 libapache2-mod-php7.1 php7.1-common php7.1-gd php7.1-mysql php7.1-mcrypt php7.1-curl php7.1-intl php7.1-xsl php7.1-mbstring php7.1-zip php7.1-bcmath php7.1-iconv php7.1-soap
```

Answer (score 1):

Oops, I figured it out by myself: gd extentions is mssing but I have already installed the mod!

```
$ service apache2 restart
```

It seems after installing php along with many modules is not enough, restarting apache is also needed!